# Mass of a solvent

Tags: temperature, physical-chemistry

We know that molality of a solution is defined to be the number of moles of solute per $kg$ mass of solvent and that it doesn't depend on temperature.

But how can a solvent (e.g water) have mass in the first place? Since solvents are fluids  which have only volume? We know $x$ liter water is equivalent to $x$ kg water. Do they mean this conversion of liter to $kg$ by mass of solvent? In that case when temperature increases,volume of water also increases,and since we are considering volume to be equivalent to mass,the mass of water should also increase as $x$ increases, then why does molality not depend of temperature?

Comment: Volume is not equivalent to mass.  Mass and volume are related through the density function, which is defined as $\rho = \frac{mass}{volume}$.

Answer (score 1):

> then why does molality not depend of temperature?

Molality is used because mass doesn't depend on temperature (in a closed system at least).

Compared to molarity (mass per volume) it is thus more accurate because it's temperature invariant.

> But how can a solvent (e.g water) have mass in the first place? Since
> solvents are fluids which have only volume?

Fluids are  material objects and thus endowed with mass, not only volume.